# Why does GETDATE keep getting called in MERGE statement?

Tags: t-sql, merge

I have a stored procedure that has a datetime var that gets set with GETDATE at the beginning of the proc and then calls a MERGE statement.

what happens is that NOT one date get's stamped but the date periodically CHANGES.  This is a long running process.

Is there a way to get ONE date and stamp that on all records?

```
create proc MyProc as
declare @insertdate datetime
set @insertdate = getdate()
merge dbo.something as target
using (select col1,col2 from dbo.another) as source
on (target.col1 = source.col1 and target.col2 = source.col2)
when not matched by target
insert (col1, col2, insertdate) values (source.col1, souce.col2, @insertdate);
```

Comment: Doesn't `insert (col1, col2, datetimeCol) values (source.col1, souce.col2, @insertdate);` work?

Comment: @MartinSmith the statement does insert the var

Comment: fyi, I had a very large on statement and ended up having a cartitian product which ended up causing the job to run a long time and over that period it was inserting multiple dates.  when i removed the cartitian product problem the same date stuck. still curious what was going on and how to avoid in the future.

Comment: It doesnt seem likely to me that this statement, called once, is updating that field.  getdate() is called once - it wouldn't follow that it is called again and re-evaluated.  Are you absolutely certain that there is no default value being set from an outside insert, or another external process updating it, or even a second call to this SP?

Comment: @chris are you certain that you weren't seeing multiple overlapping runs of the proc? It would be hard to be certain with a merge...

Comment: I'm wondering if a query producing a cartitian produce would cause some kind of recursive action in the merge statement?